# Is there a PTP (Precision Time Protocol | IEEE 1588) library?

Tags: .net, time, ieee

I've been tasked with syncing a time critical process for logging data from a PLC with a PTP (Precision Time Protocol, IEEE 1588) time source.

A quick look at the available libraries all turn up nothing but IVI-C and IVI-COM based implementations.

Is there a managed library that supports PTP that I missed, or do I need to find a method to use theIVI-COM library that is designed for LabVIEW in my application?

Comment: You have followed articles like http://openmeas.blogspot.com/2006/09/ivi-c-and-ivi-com.html ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had reffered, the following answer from this site  http://code.google.com/p/ptpv2d/wiki/Introduction, which i gave me a clear idea on ptpv2d, hope you also get the clear information, about this.

Pls refer this also http://code.google.com/p/ptpv2d/

ptpv2d is GPL licensed open source code of IEEE 1588 version 1, version 2 and IEEE 802.1AS including hardware timestamping for Freescale MPC831x family of processors.

> The ptpv2d is a Precision Time
> Protocol which has the following
> features:
>
> 1. The  User mode application which  runs under standard LINUX, with a
>    modular design that ensures easy
>    portation to additional operating
>    systems.
> 2. An extensive optional print-to-console debug message
>    function. This message functionality
>    can be added or omitted at compile
>    time. If it is included, then the
>    output level is command-line
>    selectable. Debug messages are
>    uniformly formatted for quicker,
>    easier analysis. The POSIX socket
>    calls is used to retrive  all
>    messages. Message handling is
>    contained in a separate module to
>    ensure easy portation to any desired
>    operating system.
> 3. Freescale MPC8313E Ethernet port driver with full support
>    for PTP version 1 and version 2
>    message hardware time stamping.
> 4. Ability to adjust the Hardware clock very precisely (as
>    precise as one part per billion).
>    Software algorithm for fine (as small
>    as one part per billion) adjustment of
>    the Hardware clock .
> 5. Ability to report detected variances from Grandmaster
>    clock in parts per million
> 6. Command line ability to set four different debug
>    output levels: none, basic, verbose,
>    and Message
>    7.Ability to set Sync/Follow-up transmit time values of
>    less than one second. This allows for
>    multiple Sync/Follow-ups per second,
>    which provides enhanced accuracy and
>    tracking of the "slave" system to the
>    "grandmaster" system.
> 7. Additional run time options and support code include:
> 8. Selection of PTP version 1 or version 2 encapsulation
>    and protocol
>    10.Selection of IEEE 1588 PTP over IPv4/UDP, IEEE P1588 PTP
>    over Ethernet (draft 2.2)or IEEE
>    P802.1AS encapsulation and
>    protocol(draft 1.0)  User specified
>    clock period to synthesize other base
>    clocks, not just at 10 MHz.
>
> These features have gone through
> extensive testing using dual
> MPC8313E-RDB boards running both PTP
> and Ping traffic. On a Freescale
> MPC8313E-RDB board running eight
> Sync/Follow-up Messages per second, it
> will support a plus or minus 50
> nanosecond offset from master more
> than 99.9% of the time. At 128
> Sync/Follow-ups per seconds, the
> system will synchronize within 16
> nanoseconds of the "grandmaster"
> system.

Answer (score 3):

I've created a IEEE-1588 library some time ago. It was partly difficult especially if you require good sync between clocks. Good ptp library involves a lot of statistics, prediction, and signal processing. The best you can try is [ptpd](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ptpd/) - it's very simple to learn how ptp works, and it will give you a good start.

Answer (score 2):

Look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/ptpd/

The PTP daemon (PTPd) implements the Precision Time protocol (PTP) as defined by the IEEE 1588 standard. PTP was developed to provide very precise time coordination of LAN connected computers.